# How to get data using Add-in program from Office document without metadata(i.e. creation time)?

Tags: pdf, ms-word, office-js

There's a function which retrieves document of PDF format byte by byte:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // If not using Word 2016
        if (!Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', '1.1')) {
            $('#hash-button-text').text("Not supported!");
            return;
        }

        //$('#hash-button').click(calculate_hash);
        $('#btn').click(getFile);
    });
};

function getFile() {
    Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Pdf, { sliceSize: 99 },
        function (result) {
            if (result.status == "succeeded") {
                var file = result.value;
                var sliceCount = file.sliceCount;
                var slicesReceived = 0, gotAllSlices = true, docdataSlices = [];
                getSliceAsync(file, 0, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        }
    );
}

function getSliceAsync(file, nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived) {
    file.getSliceAsync(nextSlice, function (sliceResult) {
        if (sliceResult.status == "succeeded") {
            if (!gotAllSlices) { // Failed to get all slices, no need to continue.
                return;
            }
            docdataSlices[sliceResult.value.index] = sliceResult.value.data;
            if (++slicesReceived == sliceCount) {
                file.closeAsync();
                console.log("Done: ", docdataSlices);
            }
            else {
                getSliceAsync(file, ++nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
            }
        }
        else {
            gotAllSlices = false;
            file.closeAsync();
            console.log("getSliceAsync Error:", sliceResult.error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

So, close to ~1800 byte there are bytes like `"CreationDate(D:20190218150353+02'00..."` which are unnecessary in our case.
It retrieves the whole PDF file which consists meta, but is it possible to get it without it?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

The [`document.getFileAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document#getfileasync-filetype--options--callback-) method will always return the entire document (including metadata); it's not possible to make it return anything less than the entire document.

Comment: Thank you, of course, it gets metadata, but is it possible to remove it? Also, might it be possible to get the entire archive of *.doc file from Add-in plugin of currently opened document?